# Why this won't have border line on top, right and bottom but left?

Tags: html, css

I want border line on top, bottom, left and right.
But my code apply to only left side somehow.

How can I fix it?

[DEMO@JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/wvqbh3pf/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="frame new"><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/pco91kroVgQ/hqdefault.jpg" style="
    width: 480px;
    position: absolute;
    top:-48px;
    clip: rect(50px 480px 320px 0px);
    border:solid 1px #ccc;padding:4px;
"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.frame {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 270px;
    width: 480px;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
    .frame:after,
    .frame:before {
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        content: "";
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

/* new */
.new {
    padding: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    }

.new:after {
    background: red;
    content: "New"; 
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    height: auto;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Arial';
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg);
       -moz-transform: rotate(-30deg);
            transform: rotate(-30deg);
    left: -30px;
    top: 3px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
            box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

because the image is positioned absolute inside the div and it gets cropped, you can see it in the image I attached. You can apply the border to the .frame and it will work
[image]

Comment: what if I want to crop the image and make it shrink down to 480px x 270px. Then I want border line around it.

Answer (score 1):

The edits are -

- Removed `position: absolute` from `img`
- Removed `height` and `width` from the `frame` class

```css
.frame {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 overflow: hidden;
 }
 .frame:after,
 .frame:before {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 }
 
/* new */
.new {
 padding: 1px;
 overflow: hidden;
 }

.new:after {
 background: red;
 content: "New"; 
 width: 100px;
 text-align: center;
 height: auto;
 color: #fff;
 font-family: 'Arial';
 font-weight: bold;
 padding: 5px 10px;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-30deg);
         transform: rotate(-30deg);
 left: -30px;
 top: 3px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
         box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
 }
```

```html
<div class="frame new"><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/pco91kroVgQ/hqdefault.jpg" style="
    width: 480px;
    top:-48px;
    clip: rect(50px 480px 320px 0px);
    border:solid 1px #ccc;padding:4px;
"/></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but now clip is ignored if you do that way. I have to trim very top and bottom part of the image so that I was using clip:

Comment: I'd like whole part as 480px x 270px including border line.

Comment: Then why not use `overflow: hidden` instead of `clip`?